# Create SQL table, SQLite Exception

Tags: android, sqlite

know this is a very elementary question, i keep on getting this error code on my logcat:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT_id": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT_id, name,password FROM GANDALF ORDER BY name

Would really need some advice, have tried looking at other create sqlite table post but couldnt solve it.

```
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE gandalf " +
            "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,password TEXT, category TEXT);");

}
```

And try this too

```
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE books ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                "name TEXT, "+
                "password TEXT, "+
                "category TEXT)");
```

Full code for datahelper
    public class DataHelp extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
private static final String dbname = "pass.db"; 
private static final int ver = 1;

public DataHelp(Context context) {
    super(context, dbname, null, ver);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE gandalf " +
            "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,password TEXT, category TEXT);");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void insertDB(String name, String pass){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("Name", name);
    cv.put("Pass", pass);
    db.insert("db", null, cv);
    db.close();
}

public Cursor getAll(){
    return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT_id, name," +
            "password FROM GANDALF ORDER BY name",null));
}

public String getName(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(1));
}

 public String getPass(Cursor c) {
        return(c.getString(2));
      }

 public String getCat(Cursor c) {
        return(c.getString(3));
      }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

add whitespace after `SELECT` in your `SQL` Command

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, password FROM GANDALF ORDER BY name",null);
```

Comment: You had a closing bracket too much. Fixed. I don't know why, someone downvoted while I was correcting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
```

Create Table:
     db.execSQL("create table gandalf"+"("+"id"+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+"name"+" text,"+"password"+" text,"+"category"+" text"+")");

```
Select Query:
db.rawQuery("select id,name,password from gandalf ORDER BY name",null);
```